# There is a way to update states on recoilJS outside of component?

Tags: javascript, recoiljs

So I'm trying recoilJS for a js game that I am building and it pretty neat, but the need to update atoms from components only feels like a limitation.

To create a game loop, I put all the logic on empty component so I will be able to read and write states. Even if I will construct the login outside of the component, I will need especially move different stats around all the time. There is a way to update atoms outside of react component (not via hooks)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't right now. Opened a suggestion for recoil team.

Comment: you can use react-wire. similar API, but it's possible to be used outside of the react context. see `createWire` and `createSelector` in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@forminator/react-wire.

Answer (score 7):

I use [RXJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/) to help to set RecoilJS value outside of the component.

At the start, I created 4 parts as

1. Main component
2. [RecoilJS component](https://recoiljs.org/)
3. [Atom file](https://recoiljs.org/docs/basic-tutorial/atoms)
4. set RecoilJS outside value of the component file

1).Main

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  RecoilRoot
} from 'recoil';

function App() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <MainScreens />
      <RecoilJSComponent/>
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}
```

2).RecoilJS component

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    useRecoilCallback
} from 'recoil';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

export const setRecoil = new Subject();

const getRecoil = new Subject();
const returnRecoil = new Subject();

export const promiseGetRecoil = (recoilObj) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        getRecoil.next(recoilObj)
        returnRecoil.subscribe({
            next: (value) => {
                if (recoilObj === value.recoilObj) {
                    resolve(value.value)
                }
            }
        });
    })
 }

export default function RecoilJSComponent() {

    const setStore = useRecoilCallback(({ set }) => (n) => {
        set(n.recoilObj, () => (n.value));
    }, [])

    const getStore = useRecoilCallback(({ snapshot }) => async (recoilObj) => {
    
    const valueRecoilObj = await snapshot.getPromise(recoilObj);
    returnRecoil.next({ recoilObj: recoilObj, value: valueRecoilObj })

 }, [])

    setRecoil.subscribe({
        next: (value) => {
            setStore(value)
        }
    });

    getRecoil.subscribe({
        next: (recoilObj) => {
            getStore(recoilObj)
        }
    });

    return null;
}
```

3).Atom file

```
export const textState = atom({
  key: 'textState'
  default: ''
});
```

4).set RecoilJS outside the value of the component file

```
import API from './Api';
import { setRecoil } from './RecoilJSComponent'
import { textState } from './textState'

export const setValueReCoil = () => {

    API()
        .then(result => {

           setRecoil({ recoilObj: textState, value: result })

        })
        .catch(ex => {
        
        })
};
```

The main idol is in 2 and 4

In number 2,
I create to use RXJS for setting value via the component and I export RXJS to set a value on RecoilJS outside of the component

I hope my idol can help you to resolve your problem

Comment: I created a package to fix this problem.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/recoil-outside

Have a good luck.

Comment: I just had to comment that this answer was awesome. I didn't use RxJS but rather my own sub/pub global callback, but the idea was genius. Just wanted to say thanks for putting me on the correct path.